# Console acces from a .NET Core program run at PowerShellISE prompt

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, powershell-ise

I use Visual Studio 2017 to create a basic .Net-Core 2.0 console application called  `CoreTest01` with the following code :

```
using System;

namespace CoreTest01
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
      Console.WriteLine("Enter your name :");
      String name = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine($"Your name is : {name}");
    }
  }
}
```

The build generate an assembly `CoreTest01.dll`. When I run it using the following command `Dotnet .\CoreTest01.dll`, it works nicely from the `Cmd.exe` and `Powershell.exe` prompt. But when I run it from `Powershell_ISE.exe` prompt, the program hang at the `Console.ReadLine()` line. I can just stop the program using `Ctrl C`.

When I run `[console]::ReadLine()` in `Powershell_ISE.exe` the session hung definitively.

I test it on Windows Seven (version 6.1 7601 SP1) and Windows 10 (version 1709)  with PSVersion 5.0 and 5.1 .

What is the reason ? does anybody has a workarround ?

Comment: The workaround is to not use the ISE. It is an implementation of the powershell environment but does not accurately represent the experience of powershell.exe. It is fine for writing code if you are on a system where you cannot install something better, but code should always be tested in the powershell console not in the ISE.

Comment: Do you understand why it happends ?

Comment: Not the deep dark innards of why it happens no. I believe that MS has announced that they will not be doing any further work on the ISE. There is no need IMO to make your code work with the ISE. It is just there as a convenience.